# How can I save table echoed into session?

Tags: php, mysql, session, session-variables

Here's my code:

now, how can I save these in session, so that whenever I go to new link, the table is still there. Thanks guys.

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($locate)){

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['grade'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['section'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['subject'] . "</td>";
            $namers = $row['name'];
            //echo "<td><center> <button name = 'name1' type = 'submit' value = '$namers'>Go</button> </center></td>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either store $row in a session:

```
$_SESSION['rowdata'] = $row;
```

OR serialise the $row to store it and unserialise it when you want to use it:

```
//Store
$_SESSION['rowdata'] = serialise($row);

//get back
$row = unserialise($_SESSION['rowdata']);
```

Comment: There would be an additional column per row, and it's a button. What I want to do is,  when I clicked the button, the whole row with corresponding button will disappear and the user will be transfered to a new link. Then after submitting their answers, it will go back to the table, and the 1st row must be gone to avoid re-submitting of their answers.